# How to remove added done button from numeric keyboard

Tags: iphone, keyboard, numeric

This is my code....

`

```
- ( void ) registerForKeyboardNotifications {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
}

    // Called when the UIKeyboardDidShowNotification is sent.
- ( void ) keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)notification {
    [self addButtonToKeyboard];
}

#pragma -
#pragma Numeric keyboard done button

- ( void ) keyboardDoneClicked:(id)sender {
    [txtvannum resignFirstResponder];
    [txtmobnum resignFirstResponder];
//    [sender resignFirstResponder];
}


- ( void ) addButtonToKeyboard {
        // create custom button
//    if(keyButton){
    doneButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    doneButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 163, 106, 53);
    doneButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 3.0) {
        [doneButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"DoneUp3.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [doneButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"DoneDown3.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    } else {        
        [doneButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"DoneUp.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [doneButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"DoneDown.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    }
    [doneButton addTarget:self action:@selector(keyboardDoneClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        // locate keyboard view
    UIWindow* tempWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:1];
    for(int i=0; i<[tempWindow.subviews count]; i++) {
        keyboard = [tempWindow.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
            // keyboard found, add the button
        if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 3.2) {
            if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIPeripheralHost"] == YES)
                [keyboard addSubview:doneButton];
        } else {
            if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIKeyboard"] == YES)
                [keyboard addSubview:doneButton];
            }
        }

//    }
////    else{
////        return;}

}
```

`

I developed an app which consist of user to enter their details.There are 4 text fields in that.Two among those requires numeric type of keyboard.For that numeric keyboard I added the done button to resign after finished editing.But that done button is coming for all other type of keyboard also.How can add that done button oly to numeric keyboard so that it should hide for all other type.I am struggling in this.Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: I have posted my code which I used in my app.Pls help

Answer (score 0):

For each `UITextField` use the function `setReturnKeyType:` which can attain values,

```
typedef enum {
   UIReturnKeyDefault,
   UIReturnKeyGo,
   UIReturnKeyGoogle,
   UIReturnKeyJoin,
   UIReturnKeyNext,
   UIReturnKeyRoute,
   UIReturnKeySearch,
   UIReturnKeySend,
   UIReturnKeyYahoo,
   UIReturnKeyDone,
   UIReturnKeyEmergencyCall,
} UIReturnKeyType;
```

And you have to set the key type for each text field separately.For the text field that you don't want the done button just set it as `UIReturnKeyDefault`.
 Hope this helps.

Comment: But when we set a done return key for numeric keypad its not assigning by default.So we need to add our own custom button to that.I even added that done button to that and also its working fine.But my problem is, this done button is coming for all type of keypad in that view.How can I hide or remove that btn for those textfield which using alphabetical keypad.

Comment: I had seen your code. We can use `- (BOOL) textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField` delegate of `UITextField`. So that you can find which textfield is about to bring the keyboard. Set a flag in here if the textfield is numeric. Your `keyboardWasShown:` function  definitly will called after the textfield delegate. So that you can add the button if the flag is set else you can remove the button.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to set a notification to keep tracking keyboard's activity. To identify, which UITextField is being active, you have to set an unique tag to each.

In .h file >>

```
@interface myViewController : UIViewController
{
    UITextField *txtField1; // Allows Numeric input
    UITextField *txtField2; // Allows String input
    UITextField *txtField3; // Allows Numeric input
    UITextField *txtField4; // Allows String input
    UITextField *txtFieldTemp; // Temp textfield

    BOOL isReturned;
}
```

In .m file >>

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    txtField1.tag = 0; 
    txtField2.tag = 1; 
    txtField3.tag = 2;
    txtField4.tag = 3; 
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification:(NSNotification *)note 
{
    if (txtFieldTemp.tag == 0 || txtFieldTemp.tag == 2)
    {
        [self addButtonToKeyboard];
    }
}

-(void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField.tag == 0 || textField.tag == 2)
    {
        [self addButtonToKeyboard];
    }
    else
    {
        [self removeButtonFromKeyboard];
    }
    txtFieldTemp = textField;
}
```

```
- (void)removeButtonFromKeyboard
{
   // Remove Keyboard logic
}
```